# A basic apply anonymous function

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `a` that has columns `id` and `date` and a second dataframe `b` that has `id` as its first column. For each row in `b`, I'm trying to find all rows in `a` with the same `id`, and then find the minimum of the dates. I'm using the code below, but when I run this, I'm getting a numeric as opposed to dates. I'm wondering if someone can help me with this.

```
class(a$date)
# "Date"
funP <- function(x){
    b <- subset(a, id==x[1])
    min(b$date)
}
f <- apply(b, 1, funP)
class(f)
# "numeric"
```

Comment: This is really about how to do this in R, so I voted to close and migrate to StackOverflow.com in the `r` tag. It would be good if you could edit your question to be reproducible, with small (!) examples of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the `apply` function converts date values.  The manual (`?apply`) mentions:

> **Value:**
>
> [...]
>   In all cases the result is coerced by ‘as.vector’ to one of the basic
>   vector types [...]

You could convert it back to the Date class:

```
f <- as.Date(f, origin="1970-01-01")
```

Comment: Yup, the coercion to vectors/matrices is intentional with `apply`, which is really designed for working inside matrices and by extension data frames. In situations like this, use `lapply` instead, and if you need a vector instead of a list use `unlist`. In principle, `unlist(lapply(...))` is the same thing as `sapply`, but sometimes `sapply` is unpredictable and I like having finer control.